# Can an ordered logit model be used to predict points scored by an NBA player?

Tags: distributions, discrete-data, ordered-logit

I am interested in getting the probabilities of a player scoring exactly 1 point, 2 points, 3 points etc. Can an ordered logit be used for this?

If not what would be the best way to get the probabilities of each value occurring?

[image: Distribution of Points]

Comment: The heights of your bars seems to be affected by rounding (each bar seems to correspond to slightly more than one point on average, which may be contributing to the the spikes)

Comment: The bin width is set to 1, so this shouldn't be the case, but this is just a plot of the observed values for all players. My question is can an ordered logit be used to get the probabilities for a player to score exactly 1 point, 2 points, etc. or is there a better alternative? @Henry

Comment: I had uploaded the wrong graph, I updated it to bin width of 1 @Henry

Comment: I would say "start simple"; go with a well-thought Poisson model (account for non-linear effects, grouping based on roles, team, etc.), check residuals, over-dispersion (or under-dispersion), adapt accordingly (NB? ZIP? ZINB?), repeat. (Side-note: I like that drop of people of a single point.)

Answer (score 1):

Possibly, but I think there are important deficiencies to consider.

First, ordered logit models are used when the outcome is discrete and, well, ordered.  Granted the outcome here is ordered and discrete, but it is unbounded above.  It looks like there may be one observation around 60, but is there reason to believe players can not score more than 60 points *ever*?  Probably not.

Additionally, there may be infrequent observations of very large scores making estimation difficult.

All in all, I think an ordered logit is not the right model and would rather opt for model with approprioate support on $\mathbb{N} \cup {0}$, like the poisson or negative binomial (though they may not be appropriate from what I'm seeing here).

Additionally, the variation in points can likely be explained by other factors (such as time played, position, experience, opponent defence, etc), so those should be adjusted for when possible.

Comment: My assumption was that since points can come in intervals of 1, 2, or 3 that poisson would not be appropriate, but if poisson or negative binomial would not be appropriate, what other options are there?

Comment: I am also curious why a negative binomial would not be appropriate?

Comment: @radio23  The reason the poisson/NB would not be appropriate is because it looks like 0 is over inflated.  The first and second bars are not consistent with the expected frequencies relative to the other frequencies.  Of course, this is the marginal distribution of points scored.  if you adjust for important co variables, then a poisson/NB regression may be appropriate.

Comment: +1 Demetri, I  was ready to say that this is just the marginal. I wouldn't be surprised for example if the minutes played strongly modulated this effect.